# Class instantiation is not taking place

Tags: java

This is my piece of code.

```
if (check1 != 0 && check2 != 0 && check3 != 0)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(main, "You are now signed up","Welcome", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
     new HomePage();
}
```

Here `HomePage` class instance is not created although `JOptionPane` dialogbox is shown. This code is in `SignUp.java`. `HomPage` is a class with `main` method in the same package as the above piece of code.

Why is this? What should be done to instantiate it?

HomePage.java looks like this

```
      public class HomePage extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ActionListener {
      public HomePage() {
             initComponents();
       }
      private void initComponents() {
           ...
      }
      public static void main(String args[]) {

              /* Create and display the form */
              java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                     new HomePage().setVisible(true);
              }
           });
     }
   }
```

I got the solution for this. 
I changed
    `new HomePage()` 
to 
    `new HomePage().setVisible(true);`
and it works fine.

Comment: How do you know the `HomePage` instance isn't created?

Comment: Does it throw an error? If not, it is instantiated.

Comment: It is, just not visable outside the if { } block

Comment: @shmosel not necessarily - it maybe a silent error (caught and wasn't handled for example).

Comment: @MarounMaroun, not sure what you mean by "silent error". But if the constructor didn't throw an exception, the object was instantiated.

Comment: Because homepage has a gui and is not visible @Code-Apprentice

Comment: It does not throw an error @shmosel

Comment: @shmosel How do you know how `HomePage` is implemented?

Comment: @Ticktick What do you mean it's a "gui"? What does the `HomePage` class look like? What does the constructor do? Does it create a `JFrame`? Do you explicitly call `show()`?

Comment: @Ticktick, then `HomePage` is instantiated. If something is not working as expected, you'll need to clarify what you're expecting and what's actually happening.

Comment: Please provide more code. With what you have given so far we cannot help you.

Comment: Added some more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`showMessageDialog()` blocks execution of the code. The next line will execute after the dialog is dismissed either with the OK button or the Cancel button.

Also, the variable `h` is only available within the `if` block. If you need to access it somewhere else, you need to declare it outside the `if`, either locally to the method or as a class field.

Since `h` is an instance of `HomePage` which extends `JFrame`, you simply need to display it similar to what you do in the `main()` method of `HomePage`:

```
h.setVisible(true);
```

Note that there is a huge difference between creating an instance of a class and performing actions with objects of a class.

Comment: It is not getting executed after the dialog box is dismissed.

Comment: I do not want "h"  to access outside if

Comment: @Ticktick What isn't executed? Did you set a break point or add a `System.out.println()` statement after `showMessageDialog()`? You create an object and do nothing with it. What do you expect this to do?

Comment: HomePage has a main method so I want it to get executed

Comment: @Ticktick You could call the `main()` method, but this is definitely not the best solution. What are you actually trying to do? It will help a lot if you show the `HomePage` class.

Comment: @Ticktick Edited my answer. I hope it helps.